# where to raise documentation issues?

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When a problem such as a broken link is found in the ROS documentation (for instance, the link for  "move_base_msgs/MoveBaseActionGoal" on the page http://wiki.ros.org/move_base, where should it be reported?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222114/where-to-raise-documentation-issues?/) by [Joseph Landau](https://answers.ros.org/users/5098/joseph-landau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2015-12-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It will be better if you can register from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/action/login/move_base?action=login), and Edit (see figure below) the necessary page using right menu for the corrections.

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you can't fix it yourself (fi because you don't know what would be the proper fix), then it probably makes sense to report it to the issue tracker of the corresponding package (in this case [ros-planning/navigation/issues](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues)).

As almost all pages are in some way related to packages, that would cover most of them.

---

As to your specific problem, this has been reported before (see [Bad links on wiki.ros.org/move_base: The requested URL /api/move_base_msgs/html/msg/MoveBaseActionGoal.html was not found on this server](http://answers.ros.org/question/134061/bad-links-on-wikirosorgmove_base-the-requested-url-apimove_base_msgshtmlmsgmovebaseactiongoalhtml-was-not-found-on-this-server/)), but didn't get answered. The Groovy version of the links do work (see [move_base_msgs Msg/Srv Documentation](http://docs.ros.org/groovy/api/move_base_msgs/html/index-msg.html)).

I think the issue is currently actually tracked at [ros-infrastructure/roswiki#137](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/issues/137) ("MsgSrvDoc macro limited to last ROS version"), as it's not so much a documentation issue (ie: written by humans), as it is an issue with the infrastructure auto-generating those links.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-12-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3